# How can one use the iOS 17 CLMonitor APIs to monitor for an iBeacon?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-location, ibeacon

It seems the new recommended way to work with Beacons in Swift is through a CLMonitor. As much as am I excited to be rid of delegate-style event handling, I can't get a basic example working with the new style.

There seems to be very limited documentation on the matter with the only example being Apple's from WWDC, which does not seem to be functional for me.

My code is as follows:

```swift
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

let monitorName = "BeaconMonitor"
let testBeaconId = UUID(uuidString: "EDFA3FFA-D80A-4C23-9104-11B5B0B8E8F3")!

@MainActor
public class ObservableMonitorModel: ObservableObject {
    private let manager: CLLocationManager
    
    public var monitor: CLMonitor?
    
    init() {
        self.manager = CLLocationManager()
        self.manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
    
    func startMonitoringConditions() {
        Task {
            monitor = await CLMonitor(monitorName)
            await monitor!.add(getBeaconIdentityCondition(), identifier: "Beacon")
            
            for identifier in await monitor!.identifiers {
                guard let lastEvent = await monitor!.record(for: identifier)?.lastEvent else { continue }
                print(identifier, lastEvent.state)
            }
            
            for try await event in await monitor!.events {
                print("Event", event.identifier, event)
                
            }
        }
    }
    
}

func getBeaconIdentityCondition() -> CLMonitor.BeaconIdentityCondition {
    CLMonitor.BeaconIdentityCondition(uuid: testBeaconId)
}
```

Then in `ContentView.swift` I have:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject fileprivate var locationMonitor = ObservableMonitorModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ...
        }.task {
            locationMonitor.startMonitoringConditions()
        }
    }
}
```

When ran with a spec-compliant BLE Beacon broadcasting the set UUID, the app only outputs `Beacon CLMonitoringState`, not anything from the `for try await` loop.

I've tried multiple iBeacons, like the ESP32, [this](https://github.com/lgaches/BeaconEmitter?tab=readme-ov-file) Mac app, and commercial hardware from Amazon.

I have also tried swapping the Beacon monitor for a circular geography monitor, which works fine. The app has Bluetooth and Location permissions.

Comment: You need to hold on to the Task. Use .task in the view. Floating Task like you have in startMonitoringConditions are bad practice

Comment: I can't get it to work even with `.task` or holding a reference to the `Task` in my manager class.  The old delegate-based region detection returns "inside" immediately when I turn on my beacon.

Comment: did you manage to get it working? I see the same issue.

Comment: Nope, I have not got it working yet.

Comment: One question: isn't CLMonitor object supposed to be associated somehow with the CLLocationManager? I was thinking of something like manager.addMonitor or monitor.locationManager = manager...etc

Comment: @Tony seems it has its own internal location manager, I ran some tests with the simulator with faked location and enter/exit region events came through the stream without needing to make a location manager at all. The problem I'm facing is there can only be one stream.